What is the definition of the word Politics in a legal and academic context?
The word politics is often thrown around in everyday conversation.
e.g.

Politics is a dirty game
She is playing political games in the office
He is a political animal
Political measures are being taken by senior officials in the government

More often than not, the usage is not precise. We have a vague idea of the term as human beings conversing in the English language, but has there been a clear definition in legal or academic terms?
This definition should also explain compound terms like political freedoms, political measures etc.

I can’t help but feel this isn’t actually a question about politics, in the same way as a question about the word "programming" isn’t a programming question. FWIW, the help centre provides a definition of "politics" for what is on-topic on this site.

There are lots on encyclopedias out there that define the term. Is there any particular point you are not agreeing with or would like to have more explanations about?

I’m voting to close this question because this isn’t actually a question about politics, in the same way as a question about the word "programming" isn’t a programming question.

Does any word have a single definition in the legal and academic contexts?  Many words don't even bave a single definition in just one of those contexts, let alone in both.

@JamesK You mean we can talk about politics but we cannot talk about politics? I think it's fine, just give a couple of common definitions with links (it's not for us to make that up) and be done with it.

@NoDataDumpNoContribution that would be an answer for a site like ELL which is about the meaning of words not a site that has that word in its name.

@JoeW But a site about politics should know what politics is, if only to know what is ontopic. We know the answer to this. One can surely discuss if this question should live on the main site or on meta but it has to be answered somewhere here in my opinion. Can as well combine all the information in one place. It can also be ontopic on ELL but that doesn't matter for me.

@NoDataDumpNoContribution there is plenty of different meanings depending on the context and this site isn’t about basic definitions.

@JoeW But how can we discuss high level stuff without knowing at least a good amount of the basics. If there are plenty of meanings, either the question is not clear enough and should give more context or answerers should just write a bit more.

The definition of the word "politics" is a political question if it is subsequently used to determine rules.

@NoDataDumpNoContribution If you need to add a definition of a term as part of another answer that is different then asking for a definition only. There are many different ways to define the word based on what is being asked in the question that all can be considered correct.

There are a number of variations on the definition of the term 'politics' in political science, philosophy, and the social sciences, going back to Socrates in the Western world, and to thinkers like Confucius and Laozi in the Eastern. Currently the most well-regarded modern definition is from the Political Scientist David Easton:

Politics is the authoritative allocation of values in a society

… where the term 'values' broadly refers to economic, social, legal, and ethical values.
The conventional (non-academic) usage of 'politics' or 'political' generally implies two things:

That systems of rules, standards, and procedures exist that both protect and limit the free action of individuals, and…
That some people have a knack for (or at least are inordinately obsessed with) using, manipulating, subverting, or controlling these systems, often for their own advantage.

The first three examples listed in the question fall into the second category, while the last example and the phrases in the last sentence belong to the first. But both of these conventional usages are derivable from Easton's definition by viewing that definition from a perspective of unsophisticated selfish individualism.
In general, every philosophical definition of politics starts with the understanding that:

Individual human beings can only thrive when living in communities, and…
Communities can only thrive when their individual members hold to a common set of values, understandings, and acceptable behaviors.

In short, there's a tension between individuals in a community who all want things from each other but may not want to give what others want, a tension that can only be resolved through the creation of social (non-personal) systems of regulated interaction. Politics is the process by which such systems are created, maintained, and transformed in a community. In that sense, even a grade-school bully demanding respect and obedience from smaller classmates is acting in a loosely political capacity. But in the social sciences there is normally a split between governmental politics (formal rules, structures, and procedures by which a society is governed) and social politics (less formal or informal rules, structures, and procedures that moderate social behavior in other contexts).

I mean for historical context it's just the greek word for city "polis" or for the right of the citizens of such a city to govern themselves "politeia".
From there you got words like "police" and "politics" for the executive, administrative and legal institutions governing the life within such a city state. So broadly speaking the things concerned with the decision making process of governing a larger collective of individuals. There's a plurality of ways to do that and to exercise or inhibit the exercise of power over other people and so what specifically is referred to as a political act can often vary as technically everything and nothing can be or become political of enough people care or not care about it.

According to Carl Schmitt in The Concept of the Political, there are among other ways two of defining it, the one being that state = politics. However, Schmitt disagrees with this definition because according to him, once society enters the scene, social issues (economy, religion, culture, science, education) and affairs of state mix (which happens in a democracy) and influence each other. Schmitt writes that the political is actually the conflict of your state/society against a public enemy (another state/society) and cooperation with a friend (also another state/society) against enemy. So, politics is when you are able to clearly distinguish a friend and enemy on a state/society scale.
My answer is too sloppy and dilettantish since I'm not a polisci student, but that's what I gathered from my reading of Schmitt. I suggest you read either that book or some other SE answers regarding Schmitt to get a better perspective.

Afaik Carl Schmitt was one of those philosophers that when the Nazis came to power thought he couldn't fight them and thus joined them and provided a philosophical underpinning for their own conception of the political. So defining it as us vs them narratives clearly bears the mark of such fascist underpinnings. That doesn't mean everything is garbage which he said, but it's something to consider when reading him.

But he wrote this concept of the political back in 1923
